# Pushing gems to RubyGems via Travis

Tags: rubygems, travis-ci

I've followed [these instructions](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/rubygems/) to use Travis to push my gem to Rubygems whenever I tag a release, but it doesn't seem to be working. Travis runs `git fetch --tags` after a successful build, but I get no output after that(despite the fact that the same command yields a list of tags on my local machine), and my gem remains unpublished.

My `.travis.yml` file is here:

```
rvm:
- 1.9.3
- 2.0.0
- 2.1.0
deploy:
  provider: rubygems
  api_key:
    secure: "UZ7kuAfrrDfKSsmWwiPq1kS9jThJPFcxwSEyfH2sRSy4GAqqMp/E3y3Iuqbkh6GX4NFWzPtGImxcZ+9P6yoBf9Sk+N5mfUY2zyRtcjbTYZ00jvBQLgwaAh3dTRu0NXpBchn+87p7bEwV6mo4AFiacy2k/nrLdIMiyTPuqE8a1r4="
  gem: breasal
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: theodi/breasal
```

And I create a tag like so:

`git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "First release on RubyGems"`

And I push with `git push --tags`

This seems to be the right thing to do, but I'm still having no joy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a glitch with `on: tags: true` that the condition is never met and the code will never trigger a deploy. The github issue is [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1675). The issue should be resolved soon, and in the meantime you can use a branch like `releases` to upload new versions of your gems to rubygems using `on:branch`.

**Update**: 
To fix `on:tags`, you can  do this, as referenced in the above github issue.

```
 on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to restore `on:tags` functionality